# jquery modal dialog delay to load

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog

My dialog is taking too long to load content of my partialview when I click the add button.

What am I doing wrong?

div in my Index.cshtml:

```
 <div id="dialog" title="TheTitle" style="overflow: hidden;"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
     $('#lnkAdicionar').live("click", function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            width: 608,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Novo Contato',
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("CadastroContato")',
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    context: this,
                    success: function (result) {
                        $(this).html(result).find($("#divRodapeEditar")).hide();
                    },
                });

            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $('#dialog').empty();
            },
            position: {
                my: 'top',
                at: 'top',
                of: $('#fer')
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My Controller:

```
     [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CadastroContato()
    {
        CarregarCombos();
        return PartialView("_CadastroContato");
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this.  You might try changing the ajax to post to see if that helps.  You might try splitting them.  Define the dialog, populate the dialog with the ajax call on the link click and in the success of the ajax do a dialog.load.  Good Luck

Comment: How long does your ajax take to respond?

Comment: takes 3 seconds to open the modal